# Portrait mode widescreen LCD monitor recomendation

Tags: monitoring

At my office we are planning to deploy widescreen LCD monitors in portrait mode. We bought one for testing (Samsung T220 unpivotable, so we adapted a pivotable support for it) and it doesn't have a good viewable angle in this mode, despite the specifications (170/160). In portrait mode no viewing angle is good as it is in landscape mode, even when you are staring it in a 90 degrees angle, one of the sides of the screen is brighter/darker than the other. Anyone know of any LCD widescreen monitor (preferably 22 inches 1680x1050) that is good for such mode?

Comment: Shopping Questions are (now) Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look into naturally pivot-able LCD's or screens that utilize [IPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD#IPS) LCD technology.

IPS LCDs are typically known for better viewing angles than monitors that utilize TN. I am pretty sure (judging from the price) that the *Samsung T220* is a TN screen, which is part of your problem right there. Also the monitor was not designed to be viewed in portrait mode. So as I see it you have two options:

1. Buy an IPS LCD (expensive).
2. Test out a TN screen with pivot ability out of the box.

If you Google around you should be able to find some IPS monitors that also pivot into portrait mode.

Reading Material:

[Not All LCD Panels Are Created Equal](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000991.html)

[TFT LCD @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD)

Comment: +1 panel types, the latest DELL U2311H seems like a bargain IPS panel to look into (~$250)

Answer (score 0):

shame that so many monitors are 'widescreen' these days...
I wish the 4:3 form factors were more common (and cheaper at resolutions of 1600x1200 or higher)...

not everyone wants to watch a movie on their PC.
I have a 1200x1600 (portrait mode) 20" and while I enjoy (and depend) upon the vertical size, it still feels a wee bit cramped horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 22" but I have 2 Dell 20" 2009Ws which rotate. They're quite cheap and will produce a resolution of 1680x1050. Quality is good in rotated mode. Its not a world-class killer monitor, but its good enough for the office.

In fact most Dells do rotation - eg the rather good [2407WFP](http://www.xbitlabs.com/articles/monitors/display/24inch_7.html#sect0). (well, I thought a comment about a 20" and a 24" would average out to what you wanted :) )

Answer (score 0):

LG are doing some very cheap LED-backlit monitors at the moment, and the viewing angles appear to be excellent. I'll try spinning one and let you know the model number if it looks good.

I also found that running f.lux highlights the problem much more on panels with bad viewing angles. We run some nice dell units with swivel stands, but they look terrible when rotated.

Comment: Checked out these panels - They look great in portrait mode. Unfortunately they come with a fixed stand and no mounting points! I guess you get what you pay for. The panels in question were LG E2250Vs. I also tried a non-LED panel which comes with a swivel stand, is cheap, and looks good in portrait mode - Samsung 943BWX.